# Getting error on building the project Embed Interop types Property to false

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, visual-studio-2013, office-2013

On buliding my project it says Embed Interop types Property to false.

I am using VS:2010

And MS Office 2013.

I am not able to make Property false as i am not able to find it.

Please tell me guys what needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

Try by loading the excel interop by referencing it from Programfiles folder rather than from GAC